# How to upgrade Postgres 9.2.2 to 9.2.3 on a CentOS box

Tags: postgresql

What is the correct way to upgrade Postgres to 9.2.3?

(I would prefer not to have to delete/restore my databases if possible.)

```
# rpm -qi postgresql92-server
Name        : postgresql92-server          Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 9.2.2                             Vendor: (none)
Release     : 1PGDG.rhel6                   Build Date: Mon 10 Dec 2012 07:41:24 GMT
Install Date: Thu 20 Dec 2012 02:49:30 GMT      Build Host: koji-sl6-x86-64-pg92
Group       : Applications/Databases        Source RPM: postgresql92-9.2.2-1PGDG.rhel6.src.rpm
Size        : 15648007                         License: PostgreSQL
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Mon 10 Dec 2012 07:41:29 GMT, Key ID 1f16d2e1442df0f8
URL         : http://www.postgresql.org/
Summary     : The programs needed to create and run a PostgreSQL server
Description :
The postgresql92-server package includes the programs needed to create
and run a PostgreSQL server, which will in turn allow you to create
and maintain PostgreSQL databases.  PostgreSQL is an advanced
Object-Relational database management system (DBMS) that supports
almost all SQL constructs (including transactions, subselects and
user-defined types and functions). You should install
postgresql92-server if you want to create and maintain your own
PostgreSQL databases and/or your own PostgreSQL server. You also need
to install the postgresql package.
```

CentOS version:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
```

Comment: We're missing some details. Which version of CentOS are you running? Can you provide the output of `yum repolist` and `rpm -qi postgresql-server`?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the info to the question above - if you need to know anything else just le me know.

Comment: The ***CORRECT*** way to upgrade any version of Postgres to any other version of Postgres is to [read the release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/release-9-2-3.html) for each intermediate version, and follow the appropriate steps.  The CentOS way may differ substantially from this, particularly if you're using their packages (and the latest version may simply not be available as a package yet), but that's where you should start...

Comment: Hi Voretaq, could you kindly point out where the 'appropriate steps' are please?

Comment: That text in blue is a link. Click on it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have clicked on it - it goes to the release notes, there are no instructions or 'steps' on how to upgrade.

Comment: @A4J It's right under a big heading that says `E.1.1. Migration to Version 9.2.3` - It's also expected that you are familiar with the rest of the manual, which tells you how to install *any* version of Postgres (or with your OS package manager and any os-specific differences). In this case it's telling you "You do not have to dump and restore" (unless your OS does something stupid like deleting the `PGDATA` directory during upgrades)

Comment: @voretaq7 I'm sorry but it still does not tell me how to upgrade - which is what this question is asking :/ The link you provided is just the release notes/change log - not an upgrade guide. I can't help but feel you are being deliberately flippant.

Comment: @A4J I don't really know how to be clearer: Install the new version (from a package if available, or by building it in accordance with the appropriate section of the Postgres manual - you will have to click around and read). After that you must follow any instructions given in the release notes where applicable (in this case there are none).

Comment: I just got the answer from the Postgresql IRC channel. All I needed to do was yum upgrade postgresql92

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the #postgresql IRC channel:

`yum upgrade postgresql92`

Comment: Good answer, but you'll need to have [correct PGDG repository package installed](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php).